# OPENSSL: Get PEM data from PHP

Tags: php, openssl, pem

After reading the http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php info, I've been able to find a way to recover the Pem Data.

I hope someone else can use it.

```
$pemdata = 'Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 74 F6 DD C5 04 45 2F 67 .............
    friendlyName: (cmf_pf_sw_kpsc)_B86554003_50185232Z
subject=/description=Qualified Certificate: *******/CN=JOHN DOE/DA/emailAddress=JOHN@AKME.COM/serialNumber=99999999/SN=JOHN DOE/GN=JOHN*********************/C=ES
issuer=/C=ES/emailAddress=ENTITY@AKME.COM/L=***********************
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHoTCCBomgAgMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJFUzEuMCwGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYfYWNfY2FtZXJmaXJtYV9jY0BjYW1lcmZp
*****************
'
print_r (getPemData($pemdata));

    private function getPemData($pemdata){
        $cert = openssl_x509_read( $pemdata );

        // Parse the resource and print out the contents.
        return openssl_x509_parse( $cert );
    }
```

It will return an array with something like:

```
Array
(
    [name] => /description=Qualified Certificate: *******/CN=JOHN DOE/DA/emailAddress=JOHN@AKME.COM/serialNumber=99999999/SN=JOHN DOE/GN=JOHN*********************/C=ES
issuer=/C=ES/emailAddress=ENTITY@AKME.COM/L=***********************
    [subject] => Array
        (
            [description] => Qualified Certificate: *******
            [CN] => JOHN DOE
            [emailAddress] => JOHN@AKME.COM
            [serialNumber] => 99999999
            [SN] => JOHN DOE
            [GN] => JOHN
            .............
            [C] => ES
        )
...........
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: You are right. It is not a question. I've been trying to find the way to get the pem info from a while and finally I solved it. As I didn't find any example on stackoverflow I just wanted to share it.

Comment: I know is a old question but you would have asked and answered your own question, that would be better